# php displays not writable file - rights are set correctly

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
<?php
    $error = FALSE;
    $filename = "main.log";
    if(is_writable($filename) == FALSE){
        echo "Not writable.<BR />";
        $error = TRUE;
    }
    $currentFile = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    $date = date("Y-m-d");
    $time = date("H:i:s");
    $user = "not logged in";
    $action = "Run";
    $state = "OK";
    $content = $date . "\t" . $time . "\t" . $currentFile . "\t" . $action . "\t" . $user . "\t" . $state . "\t\n";
    echo "String length: " . strlen($content) . "<BR />";

    echo $content;

    $fw = file_put_contents($filename, $content);
    if($fw === FALSE){
        $error = TRUE;
        echo "Unable write to log.<BR />";
    }
    else{
        echo "<BR />Number of written bytes: " . $fw . "<BR />";
    }

    if($error == TRUE){
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>Error!</strong> Unable write to log.</div>';
    }
    echo getmyuid().':'.getmygid();
    echo "<BR />End of script";
?>
```

The output of this file is:

```
**Not writable**.
String length: 66
2016-06-20  22:10:29    setup-login.php Run not logged in   OK  
Number of written bytes: 66
33:33 // owner:group
End of script
```

I don't understand why `main.log` isn't writable and is empty because the rights of the file are:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data     0 čen 20 22:10 main.log
```

this file is created by other php script in the same folder. This script is able to write to this file. I tried also to set rights of this file manualy to 777, but also no success. This problem also happens with `fwrite()` function. So that's why I use `file_put_contents`.

This script is located in folder called auditPc. It's rights are:

```
drwxrwxr-x  7 www-data www-data 4096 čen 20 22:10 auditPc
```

Comment: Maybe you're checking wrong file? Check paths

Comment: Check if the script which creates your `main.log` file is not changing file permissions and check the user the second script is running under.

Comment: `main.log` is in the same folder as `setup-login.php`?

Comment: @LukasHajdu the rights are the same 33:33 it doesn't change owner and also the permissions.

Comment: @JeffPuckettII Yes, it is.

Comment: just to make sure of the web user account, what's the output of `echo exec('whoami');`?

Comment: @JeffPuckettII www-data. I still don't know where is a problem. I have discussed it already in my country with the programmers and nobody knows.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this question as put is *not* reproducible. Your script works fine for me as is.

Comment: @JeffPuckettII This told me also my friends, but I'm not lying. I also tried to reinstall apache2 and also PHP, but no success. But thank you!